# Moving data from html form to a chart in a MySQL databse using python

Tags: python, mysql, database, html, server

I went through a basic web.py tutorial on how to set up a basic server using MySQL and I have a database named 'testdb' with a chart 'todo' inside of it. The values I'm trying to move into the chart are 'email', 'username', and 'password' from the form in index.html. I get the error message 405 method not allowed. And after breaking past 100+ error messages I'm stumped. I already have columns for the three but i have no value assigned to them.
I'm running on a Linux Ubuntu Desktop, in the gedit test editor.

MySQL chart as seen in Terminal

```
| Field    | Type                | Null |     | Default |
_________________________________________________________
| email    | varchar(50)         | YES  |     | NULL    |               
| username | varchar(50)         | YES  |     | NULL    |
| password | varchar(50)         | YES  |     | NULL    |
```

The code for index.html

```
$def with (todos)

$for todo in todos:

<title>Red.Koala</title>

<body id="background">

<div id="header">
-> Red.Koala <-

</div>

<div id="sign">

<form action="LANForum" method="post">

<table id="tr">
    <tr>
        Sign In:<br>
    </tr>
</table>

    Email:<br>
<input id="signbox" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Ex: JoeSmith@example.com" required><br>

    Username:<br>
<input id="signbox" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username..."required><br>

    Password:<br>
<input id="signbox" height="30" type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password..." required><br>

<input value="Submit" type="submit" id="signbox" style="margin-top: 20px; right: 5px; width: 50%;">
</div>
</form>

</div>

<div id="copyright">
@HaydnFleming
</div>
<style>
#background {
    background: #ff3333;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 960px;
}
#header {
    border: solid #cc0000;
    border-width: 15px;
    font-size: 65px;
    text-align: center;
}
#sign{
    border: solid #cc0000;
    border-width: 15px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30%;
    height: 40%;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top: 40px ;
    margin-bottom: 20%;
}
#signbox {
    width: 60%;
    height: 10%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
#copyright{
    bottom: 2%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
}
#tr {
    border: solid #cc0000;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: transparent;
    border-left: transparent;
    border-right: transparent;
}
.dscrptn{
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}
.dscrptn_p{
    width: 60%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 4%;
    position: relative;
    border: solid #cc0000;
    border-width: 0px;
}
</style>
</body>
```

The code for Code.py (using Web.py)

```
import web

render = web.template.render('templates/')

urls = (
    '/', 'index', '/add', 'add', '/LANForum', 'LANForum'
)

db = web.database(dbn = 'mysql', user = 'testuser', pw = 'MServer', db = 'testdb')

class index:
    def GET(self):
        todos = db.select('todo')
        return render.index(todos)

class add:  
    def POST(self):
        i = web.input()
        n = db.insert('todo', email=i.email, username=i.username, password=i.password)
        raise web.seeother('LANForum')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

The code for LANForum.html

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="LANForum.css">

<title>Red.Koala</title>

<body id="background"> <!-- Only used to set up the main background colors/any images.-->

<div id="title"> 
<!-- I decided to use the title as a nest 
for all the other divs to rest in that way 
they could all run off of the same measurements,
and they could line up easily using similar 
percentages and pixel distances-->

    <down>Red.Koala</down> 
    <!--"down" is just a random word I used as a tag so that I could
separate the text form the divs. also the "+ [Current Forum Title]"
part means that when the website is actually running you will be able
to see the website name and then the forum title. example: Red.Koala/Funny -->

    <div id="user">[This is where the current users information will go]</div><!-- User information in the top right-->

    <div id="list">[This is where a list of pop. forum topics will go.]</div>
    <!-- List of popular forums located on the middle right of the page.-->

    <div id="mforum">[This is where your main forum will go.]
    <!-- Forum that you are currently on displayed in the big box in the middle of the screen.-->
    <div id="post-bar"><!-- Section of the Forum section where any and all posting/commenting will be done -->
    <form action="" onsubmit=""><!-- Assigned to whatever server space we select -->
    <textarea id="text-box" type="text" placeholder="Post..."></textarea>
    <!-- The box which the user will type in to post or comment things -->
    <input id="post-button" type="submit" value="Post" required>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div id="buttons"><!-- page numbers on display for the user to switch between pages.--> <!--currently not working as buttons-->

    <table>

        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>          <!-- Each cell contains a different page number-->
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>
</body>
```